# PyCharm can't autocomplete for a locally installed package included in a conda environment

Tags: python, package, pycharm, conda

I have a package I wrote called RoboPy installed locally on my computer, located in some directory "robopydir". My PyCharm project is using a conda environment as its interpreter, and the RoboPy package was pip installed into that conda environment. The installation is working and everything runs just fine, and the RoboPy package shows up on the list of installed packages both through conda list and in the PyCharm interpreter settings.

However, PyCharm can't autocomplete anything in the RoboPy package, it doesn't recommend or autocomplete it for imports, and it can't find the docs for the package. As far as I can tell it's not a problem with the conda environment, as I can autocomplete for anything else installed in this conda environment. I thought the issue might be because, while the conda site-packages directory has a RoboPy directory, it doesn't contain the source code (just some metadata and a wheel). I've tried manually adding the robopydir directory to the interpreter file paths but that didn't fix anything either.

What am I doing wrong here? Did I do something wrong writing the setup.py file for this package, which is making it not install correctly for the conda environment? And, for the future, what's the preferred or clean way to take care of this? If I have a locally written package, it seems stupid to copy it into my own conda environment folder, but that seems like the only solution I can think of right now.